# Rich push notifications in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to integrate push notification in smartface. But, this push notifications are only simple text. 
Is there any way i can configure rich push notifications like,

[image]

Notification which is combination of images and text.

Please help to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use :

```
LocalNotification( 
     id,fireDate, alertTitle, alertBody, alertAction,
     userInfo, launchImage, applicationIconBadgeNumber,
     hasAction, repeatInterval, sound, smallIcon, autoCancel,
     number, when, usesChronometer, vibrate, ticker, subText,
     priority, actions, progress, bigText, bigPicture
 );
```

[Notifications API](http://docs.smartface.io/#!/api/Notifications)

Comment: Is this method will give same kind of image and text notification as i mentioned? and how to trigger the same from server?